# Do I need to define extent when I define a new projection?

Tags: coordinate-system, georeferencing, proj

GGRS87 (EPSG:2100) is the projection system for Greece. But there is also another projection system which caters for a complex of islands (Kastellorizo, etc) which are located east form Greece (near Turkey). I have created this new projection with the following parameters
(+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=27 +k=0.9996 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=-199.87,74.79,246.62,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs).

I have digitized some polygons on these islands with the help of some orthophotos. However, these orthophotos were not on the correct location. They are inside the extent of the area for GGRS87 and not near Turkey. I saved this shapefile to the new projection. The map of the extent of the CRS for the shapefile shows that the area of the projection system is located on the west side of Africa.
[image] On the contary, the map of the extent of the CRS for the whole project shows that the area of the projection system is near Turkey (which is the correct location).
[image]

How is this possible? Has the fact that I did not determine the extent when I created the new projection played a role in it?
In addition you can download the polygon shapefile [here](https://1drv.ms/u/s!Atq-s6oCoYOzhwUfKuchRa9FJaiJ).

Comment: defining extent should not be an issue. doesn't look like a coordinate issue. It looks like geographic coordinates taken as cartogrphic coordinates (you are near the 0,0). It is unclear to me where the problem come from. Could you provide the coordinates at each step ?

Comment: Can you become more detailed? What coordinates do you want to provide?

Comment: the coordinates of the orthophotos (e.g. upper left corner) and the coordinates of one vertex of one digitized polygon

Comment: the coordinates of the bottom left corner of one orthophoto are 730000, 4003500.

Comment: You can read the extent from the layer properties, metadata tab, properties window in QGIS. It seems the projection uses `+lon_0=30` instead of 27. An offset of about 300m remains though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You can download the data from the hyperlink "here" in the question. Despite the fact that I saved as the shapefile in the new projection, the location of the data remained the same.

Comment: The CRS of the orthophoto is wrong, so the digitizing result is also. For kastelorizo, the x values in the custom CRS should be around 730000, but in your shapefile they are around 460000. In EPSG:2100 they would be around 1000000. That's about 3 degrees shift (the difference between EPSG:2100 and your custom CRS), but in the wrong direction.

Comment: Try this workaround: assign your custom CRS to your shapefile, reproject it to EPSG:2100 and a different name, then assign your custom CRS to the resulting shapefile.

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but the result is not correct (the polygons are approximately located in the correct location). Check the image (https://1drv.ms/u/s!Atq-s6oCoYOzhwZFGi6_xiQzDm8D)

Comment: Yes, I got the same. You might use the experimental vector bender plugin to get it right. If you load the orthophoto with the correct CRS, does it align better with the OSM background?

Comment: The orthophotos are in .jp2 format and there is also the respective (.jpw) file for every orthophoto in the same folder. Should I just change the CRS of orthophotos in QGIS or should I reproject them?

Comment: The jpw adds the extent in a certain CRS to the image. Surely you have to reproject (not using save as, but via the raster menu)  if you want a different CRS. But you have to know which CRS is originally assigned to the image.

Comment: The CRS of the orthophotos is GGRS87. I tried to reproject the orthophotos but the process failed "Translating source or target SRS failed".